# Angular 9 with MSAL v2 compatibilty

Tags: angular, typescript

I just migrated a project from Angular 8 to Angular 9 and I want to implement MSAL replacing Adal Package. is the compatibility of MSAL v2 with Angular 9 correct? Thank you!

I want to implement this package in my Angular project and not use ADAL anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSAL Angular v2 supports Angular 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14.

source: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/FAQ.md